# basic query join tables

Tags: sql-server

i have a master table mail:

| mail |
| --- |
| mail1 |
| mail2 |

and several tables of different systems like this:

| user xxx | mail |
| --- | --- |
| First | mail1 |
| Second | mail2 |

only field in common is mail...

i want a single table that contains the different user columns, and BLANK if user is not found...

| user xxx | user yyyy | user zzzz | mail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | fiirst y | first z | mail1 |
| Second | second y | BLANK | mail2 |

seems easy but im very RUSTY.

regards

Comment: Hello, oso_togari. Welcome to DBA SE. Please, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello Ronaldo, thanks....you think my question needs more explanation?

Comment: A question like yours should have the create statement and the the insert for the sample data (and the query you tried so far so that we can advise you about your mistake).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to do outer joins to the user tables. Since you didn't provide create statement and the the insert for the sample data, I can only guess it should be something like:

```
select xxx.xxx userxxx, yyyy.yyyy useryyyy, zzzz.zzzz userzzzz, mail.mail
from mail left outer join xxx
       on mail.mail = xxx.mail
          left outer join yyyy
       on mail.mail = yyyy.mail
          left outer join zzzz
       on mail.mail = zzzz.mail;
```

Note that SQL will return `NULL` for unmatched value in outer join. You can use `COALESCE` function if you want the literal "BLANK", like `COALESCE(xxx.xxx, 'BLANK')`

Comment: You understand it PERFECT, and this is the correct answer....LEFT OUTER JOIN....thanks Fat P......i can't vote your answer, because i have not rep enough...

Comment: @oso_togari, you can mark it as the correct answer using the tick beneath the downvote arrow.